# Change my Xbox live Subscription to PayPal

Tags: xbox-network

I have added my Paypal account to my Xbox profile, and I want to remove my existing credit card (where my live subscription gets paid) and move the billing onto Paypal. Does anyone know how (even if) you can do this.

With all the hacking attacks on big companies recently, I'm trying to remove as many saved cards as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click [here](http://live.xbox.com/account). On "Account Information", there's a link to manage your payment options.

Comment: Found it, i had to go through the membership options page and it would let me swap on there